# Python process crashes when trying to fit CatBoost model

Tags: python, anaconda, catboost

I have win64-system with Anaconda3 installed on a Windows Server 2012R2 machine (Intel Xeon CPU X5650).

CatBoost module was installed perfectly, but when i try to fit the model (ex. CatBoostRegressor) the python process crashes.

Does anynone know how to deal with this problem?

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq3kR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. Python was crashing. I investigated my variables and there were few variables with missing data.

Imputed them and it worked fine. Maybe you can try imputing your missing data, before fitting catboost